# Caching using PLSQL table not working

Tags: oracle, session, caching, plsql

I have the below code which i have written to debug some information

I want to call GLOBAL.INIT which needs to be called only once per user session

Hence i have used PLSQL table to cache the value and if the SID is different then again call GLOBAL.INIT but the caching is not working,Kindly help me

```
create or replace procedure dbg(message in VARCHAR2) is
  sid1 NUMBER;
  idx  NUMBER;
  Type sidcache is table of NUMBER index by binary_integer;
  sidcache1 sidcache;
  sid2      NUMBER;
begin

    select sid
      into sid1
      FROM v$session se
     where se.audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'sessionid');
    BEGIN
    sid2 := sidcache1(sid1);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      sidcache1(sid1) := sid1;
      global.INIT('100', 'SYSTEM');
      dbms_output.put_line(1);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
  END;
  WRITE_DEBUG.pr_debug('LD', message);
end dbg;
```

EDIT#1:-

After trying Mike's answer the same requirement was acheived using the below

```
create or replace procedure dbg(message in VARCHAR2) is
sid2      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  sid2 := WRITE_DEBUG.sidcache1(1);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    WRITE_DEBUG.sidcache1(1) := 1;
    global.INIT('100', 'DEBUG');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END; 
WRITE_DEBUG.pr_debug('LD', message);
end dbg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default PL/SQL variables are initialised each time the block is entered and the values are not carried across calls. This means that each time you call this procedure, the sidcache1 variable will be null.

An easy way to get around this would be to declare sidcache1 as a variable in a package. Package variables are initialised once per session, with each session having their own unique set of variables. I don't think you would even need to store the SID, a Boolean might even be sufficient to record if global.init has been called.

Comment: thank you so much,replaced getting sid with just number variable and it is working fine